# Sorting an array alphabetically string with numbers

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been trying to sort a list of titles in alphabetical order, however, there are titles which are not sorting in the way i'd like them to.

**Here is my current code:**

```
$documents = get_posts(array(
                    'post_type' => 'maps_document',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'orderby' => 'title',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'maps_document_category',
                            'terms' => $category->slug,
                            'field' => 'slug'
                        )
                    )
                ));

                usort($documents, function($a, $b) {
                    preg_match('/^Year (\d+)/', $a->post_title, $a_matches);
                    preg_match('/^Year (\d+)/', $b->post_title, $b_matches);
                    $a_year = $a_matches[1] ?? 0;
                    $b_year = $b_matches[1] ?? 0;

                    if ($a_year !== $b_year) {
                        return $a_year - $b_year;
                    } else {
                        return strcasecmp($a->post_title, $b->post_title);
                    }
                });
```

**And the output it's generating:**

```
Enrolment 2023
Enrolment Timeline for Year 7
Instrumental Music – Expressions of Interest Form and Payment 2023
Instrumental Music – Re-Enrolment Form and Payment 2023
Prospectus 2023
Senior School Handbook
Uniform List 2022
Year 6-7 Non Government School Placement Pack
Year 7 Booklist 2023
Year 8 Booklist 2023
Year 9 Booklist 2023
Year 9 Handbook
Year 10 & VCE Booklist 2023
```

**And the desired output should be:**

```
Enrolment 2023
Enrolment Timeline for Year 7
Instrumental Music – Expressions of Interest Form and Payment 2023
Instrumental Music – Re-Enrolment Form and Payment 2023
Prospectus 2023
Senior School Handbook
Uniform List 2022
Year 10 & VCE Booklist 2023
Year 9 Handbook
Year 9 Booklist 2023
Year 8 Booklist 2023
Year 7 Booklist 2023
Year 6-7 Non Government School Placement Pack
```

---

Going crossed eyed with the code. Any suggestions?

see my message above for all the details on everything

Comment: So how do you wish to use year `6-7`? How will `6-7` compare with `7` or `8`?

Comment: Why not simply try `$b_year - $a_year` instead of `$a_year - $b_year`? BTW I find it strange that you want to sort alphabetically ascending and numerically descending in the same sort, but you must have a reason

Comment: Add a sortorder column to the table and assign the values as you want to have it sorted...